# How to get the actual object passed to a logging call from a logging.Handler

Tags: python, logging

Suppose I do the following:

```
import logging

some_obj = MyObject()
logging.info(some_obj)
```

and I have a `logging.Handler` that handles this message:

```
class MyHandler(logging.Handler):

    def emit(self, record):
         # ...
```

Is there a way to get a reference to `some_obj` from my handler? From the documentation for [`logging.LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord), it would appear I can only get the string representation of the log invocation (i.e. the first argument merged with any formatting arguments to follow) through `record.getMessage()`.

I'd like to do this so I can use properties/methods of the object to more cleanly handle logic in the handler. Otherwise I have to base my handler logic on the contents of the string which will end up getting ugly very fast for this particular use case.

Please let me know if there is any additional context required to answer this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a logging subclass and override [`makeRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.makeRecord)

Comment: Were you looking for `msg` and `args` (which are documented in the ["LogRecord attributes"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) section about a page down from where your link goes)?

Comment: If you're looking for a more structured way to access logged data, I've heard good things about [structlog](http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/), which uses a key-value design instead of orienting everything around format strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `some_obj` will be stored in the `msg` attribute of the `LogRecord`: this simple script

```
import logging

class MyClass(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'foo'

class MyHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        print('%r: %s' % (record.msg, record.msg))

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(MyHandler())
some_obj = MyClass()
logger.warning(some_obj)
```

should print something like this when it's run:

> <__main__.MyClass object at 0x0000000002934400>: foo

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize record.msg was exactly what I was looking for. For some reason, I thought the logging framework would have already converted the argument to a string at this point. This will work!